# How to add current_date + one day?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I want to add days to the current_date  for example 1 day I have a tree view I check if due_date  greater than current date to make line red color

```
<tree string="class gradebooks Tree" colors="red:due_date &gt; current_date">
```

So how to add days to current date?

Comment: You want add days of week ? Like 5th day of week i.e. Friday OR days of year i.e. 250th day on the reference of current date ?

Comment: yes i want to add one day to the current date to check if due_date > tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You could create a calculated field to return the current date value or tomorrow date value to be able to check against it, put it as an invisible field in your tree definition and use it in your colors condition

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new compute field with your logic

```
is_overdue = fields.Boolean(compute='_comute_overdue', default=False)

def _compute_overdue(self):
        today = fields.Date.context_today(self)
        for record in self:
            // your logic here
            if record.due_date > today:
                record.is_overdue = True
```

and in the treeview

```
<tree colors="red:is_overdue==True">
```